# How to exclude an escape character from being treated as an escape character

Tags: java, string, unicode, escaping

I have a Java string

```
String t = "Region S\u00FCdost SER";
```

where \u00FC is a replacement for the unicode character "ü"

If i add a new escape char to the above string, i would still want my below function to escape other chars excluding the current .

For example, the below function on re running would return the result as "Region S\\u00FCdost SER" and "Region S\\\\u00FCdost SER" on subsequent iterations.

How do we prevent this?

```
public static String escapeString(String str)
    {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

        // char is 16 bits long and can hold an UTF-16 code        
        // i iterate on chars and not on code points
        // i guess this will be enough until we need to support surrogate pairs 
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            switch (c) {

            case '"':
                result.append("\\\""); //$NON-NLS-1$
                break;
            case '\b':
                result.append("\\b"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                break;
            case '\t':
                result.append("\\t"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                break;
            case '\n':
                result.append("\\n"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                break;
            case '\f':
                result.append("\\f"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                break;
            case '\r':
                result.append("\\r"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                break;
            case '\'':
                   result.append("\\'"); //$NON-NLS-1$   

                break;
            case '\\':

                result.append("\\\\"); //$NON-NLS-1$

                break;

            default:
                if (c < 128)
                {
                    //is ascii
                    result.append(c);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.append(
                            String.format("\\u%04X", (int) c)); //$NON-NLS-1$
                }
            }
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't, compiler before creating binaries is changing all Unicode notation `\uXXXX` with its proper characters, so in binaries `String t ` is ending with `ü`, not `\u00FC`. (This is also why we can write comment like `//\u000a System.out.println("hello");` and see `hello` on the screen)

Comment: @Pshemo Maybe he is passing the string as a runtime input

Comment: @Hackerdarshi My assumption is based on "I have a Java string `String t = "Region S\u00FCdost SER";`". If that string comes from some outside resource which explicitly sends characters ``\`` `u` `restOfUnicode` then question should mention it.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi If he passes the string `Region S\u00FCdost SER` at runtime, then the Java string literal should be `Region S\\u00FCdost SER` in which case you'd get the \\, then \\\\, and so on results.

Comment: @Andreas AFAIK no. "_If he passes the string Region S\u00FCdost SER at runtime, then the Java string literal should be Region S\\u00FCdost SER_" **correct**. But, `\\` will be escaped! So,  "_in which case you'd get the \\, then \\\\, and so on results_" No.

Comment: @Andreas in comments to add code formatting to \  surround it with double `\``. Like ``\`` was created with `\`\`\\`\``.

Comment: @Pshemo Too late, more than 5 mins, but thanks, I'll remember that for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
case '\\':
    if(str.charAt(i+1)!='u')
        result.append("\\\\");
    else 
        result.append("\\");
break;
```

Assuming that `\u` will always denote a unicode character sequence in your string.

Comment: The method never sees a `\uXXXX` sequence, because the original string has been unescaped by the compiler, so the string seen by the method is `"Region Südost SER"`.

Comment: @Andreas As I have said in a comment to the question, "Maybe he is passing the string as a runtime input"...

Comment: Will \u always denote a Unicode? I had my solution exactly similar to what you have mentioned. Is there a cleaner way to deal this problem ? :) if not can I extract the 3 chars following \u to check if it's an decoded Unicode in addition to what you have mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

When you write a Java string literal as `"Region S\u00FCdost SER"`, the Java compiler will interpret that as the string value `Region Südost SER`, which is what the `escape()` method will see when called on `t`.

If you wanted the string `Region S\u00FCdost SER`, you should have escaped the \ , i.e. `"Region S\\u00FCdost SER"`.

If you keep running the `escape()` method, I believe you'll see what you want.

```
String s = "Region S\u00FCdost SER";
System.out.println(s); // print original text
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    s = escapeString(s);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:

```
Region Südost SER                           <-- original text
Region S\u00FCdost SER
Region S\\u00FCdost SER
Region S\\\\u00FCdost SER
Region S\\\\\\\\u00FCdost SER
```

If you change input to `"He'd say: \"Bitte schön\""`, you get:

```
He'd say: "Bitte schön"                     <-- original text
He\'d say: \"Bitte sch\u00F6n\"
He\\\'d say: \\\"Bitte sch\\u00F6n\\\"
He\\\\\\\'d say: \\\\\\\"Bitte sch\\\\u00F6n\\\\\\\"
He\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'d say: \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Bitte sch\\\\\\\\u00F6n\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"
```

I mean, this is what you wanted, right? If not, please clarify question by actually showing example output of what you want.

Comment: Okay. My question is more in terms of preventing the addition of extra escapes in the string input as you had mentioned with the change in input. How can this be programmatically prevented?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by *"preventing the addition of extra escapes"*. If the string contains a ``\`` and the method is supposed to escape the string, then *every* ``\`` becomes ``\\``. This means that 3 ``\`` becomes 6 ``\``. That's the way it's supposed to work, so double and triple escaping a string will cause many backslashes.